# Custom IME based on sms conversation phone number

Tags: android

I'm building a custom IME soft keyboard from the Android sample. Is there any way for me to find out what the phone number/contact info is of the conversation that the keyboard is open in?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only get the details of the EditText attached to the IME and no other details.

Further every OEM has a customised app and some users might as well have installed third party SMS apps, so getting the details might not be possible

Comment: you can us inputConnection.getExtractedText to get the text in the edittext

Comment: I'm able to get the text already, I'm looking to find out what application the keyboard is open with. So that i can make some changes based on whether the user is writing a text message or  typing a url in the web browser